# How to know whether Spark is running in standalone mode or running on Yarn?

Tags: apache-spark

In my cluster sever, Spark is already being deployed.
(Someone has set ip up and left quite a long time ago)

I want to know whether Spark is running in standalone mode or running on Yarn.

How can I check it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have access to the Spark UI - navigate to the "Environment" tab and search for "master" configuration:

[image]

[image]

If it says **yarn** - it's running on YARN... if it shows a URL of the form `spark://...` it's a standalone cluster.

Comment: This might seem like a silly question, but if I run `yarn application -list` and my process ID is in the output, then this must mean that it's running in `yarn` mode, right? If not, how would you identify from the command line whether Spark is using `yarn` or not?

Comment: standalone cluster it means  with workers also ?